# How to install Eclipse C/C++ in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, eclipse, c++, eclipse-cdt

To clean install Eclipse for C/C++ on Ubuntu 18.04 I tried `sudo apt install eclipse eclipse-cdt`. It's showing an error, see the log file....

```
log file.....
!SESSION Fri Aug 16 14:39:20 IST 2019 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2019-08-16 14:39:20.065
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Answer (score 4):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install ubuntu-make g++
umake ide eclipse-cpp
```

To launch Eclipse click the Eclipse CPP icon in the Dash or launch Eclipse CPP from the terminal with the following command:

```
eclipse-cpp
```

On the first launch, you'll be asked to select the workspace directory. The default workspace directory should work just fine.

---

[Cevelop](https://www.cevelop.com/) is a free C++ IDE for professional developers which is based on Eclipse. Cevelop extends Eclipse CDT with many additional features: CUTE unit testing with Test Driven Development support, new refactorings and quick fixes, and much more.

To install Cevelop in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install cevelop --beta --classic
```

Comment: ERROR: Download page changed its syntax or is not parsable

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version the binary file name could be `eclipse`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make

umake  --list-available # check the list 
umake ide eclipse-cpp
```

Then check the binary file name: `$HOME/.local/share/umake/ide/eclipse-cpp/` (default). 
Then write this to your .bashrc and good to go: `export PATH="$HOME/.local/share/umake/ide/eclipse-cpp/:$PATH"`

```
$ exec bash
$ eclipse
```